# When deploying a Graph Engine Server to a Azure API App I am getting the error below

Tags: azure, graphengine

```
Failed to start HTTP server. HTTP endpoints are disabled
```

Any ideas on how to enable the HTTP endpoints defined in the Graph Engine Server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From The Graph Engine Team,

Currently, the only supported way of deploying Graph Engine to Azure is to use Trinity via IaaS: create Windows VMs, install .NetFramework, and deploy Graph Engine Apps.

Comment: I believe this is because it requires "Full Trust", and/or it has a low level C++ layer.